# Gmail email conversation always going to archive

Tags: gmail, gmail-archive, gmail-conversations

My email conversation automatically always archives and I want them to remain in my inbox. When I am looking for the email, I have to do a search. I have checked off "Conversation group" but it still groups the conversation and sends to archive. Is there anything I can change in the settings?

Answer (score 2):

Gmail does not automatically archive anything unless you tell it to do so. Check your Gmail filters to see which of them have the "Skip the Inbox" action checked.